# kotlin Set edit text gives null object reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, simpledateformat

I just try to learn kotlin and I know it's something easy that i missed, but this Kotlin is freaking confusing... everything you do is complicated there is nothing"easy" with kotlin

Ok, so i want to set the cuurent date in an edittext (ins_from) but i get object null reference when the fragment is created... i guess i have to set the text after the fragment and editttext is created (?)

here is my kotlin file:

```
package com.example.mycarskot
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.frg_new_car.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_frg_main.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

public class frg_new_car : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        

        var cal = Calendar.getInstance()

        val dateSetListener = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

            val myFormat = "mm.dd.yyyy" // mention the format you need
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
            ins_from.setText(sdf.format(cal.time))
        }
       ins_from.setText(SimpleDateFormat("mm.dd.yyyy").format(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        

       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_new_car, container, false)



        }


}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Kotlin. You are attempting to use widgets before you create them. Leave your `return inflater.inflate()` line in `onCreateView()`, and move all of the rest of your code to an `onViewCreated()` function. This is covered in most books and courses on Android app development that discuss fragments.

Comment: i put my code in onViewCreated() it doesn't give null object reference error but it does nothing, it's like getting ignored

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare said, i needed to put my code in onViewCreated()
Now it works, thank you :)

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        var cal = Calendar.getInstance()

        val dateSetListener =
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

                val myFormat = "mm.dd.yyyy" // mention the format you need
                val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
                ins_from.setText(sdf.format(cal.time))
            }

        ins_from.setText(SimpleDateFormat("mm.dd.yyyy").format(System.currentTimeMillis()))

        ins_from.setOnClickListener {
            this.activity?.let { it1 ->
                DatePickerDialog(
                    it1, dateSetListener,
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                ).show()
            }
        }


    }
```